# AWS Route 53 not routing to Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a domain at Godaddy, an AWS elastic load balancer pointing to Elastic Beanstalk.

I am using `Route 53` to route requests to my domain to load balancer, the nameservers of Route 53 have been updated on godaddy and it's been more than 48 hours. (I even got confirmation email)

My domain is https://sreeram.rocks/

My website is running successfully at public ip: http://13.126.165.226

But for some reason domain name is not working. Can someone say Am I missing out on something that I need to configure?

**Route 53:**
[image]

**Godaddy DNS**
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: The IP resolves to the IP address you mentioned (13.126...). The problem does not seem to be DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using https, when you are using the https://sreeram.rocks/ address and http when you are using the ip, http://13.126.165.226. You need to add a certificate to your domain, you can easily do that in the certificate manager in AWS. You then need to add the domain to the elastic load balancer once it is verified.

This assuming that you have setup everything else correct with target group etc. I assume that 13.126.165.226 is one of the load balancers IP addresses and not the server itself.

Comment: and of course you need to open port 443 in you security group if you want https to work.

Comment: Thank you, just created the certificate. My inbound rules on EC2 are set to `all traffic` and `all ports` and `all protocol`, is it good enough?

Comment: From a security perspective I would only have port 80 and 443 open, if it is a web server. An redirect everything on port 80 to port 443 to enforce https, you can do that on the load balancer.